# R how to perform loop from list of txt file?

Tags: r

I am newbie in R. I have `getWordid` function and I have a list like `c(5883, 1379)`. The `for` loop I use is as below. It works for that list.

```
for (wordID in c(58843, 1379)){

  getWordid(wordID)
  cat(paste0(c(wordID, getWordid(wordID))),"\n") 

}
```

But if I want to use a list from txt file (100 rows) which it in 1 column only how to code it in for loop.

Comment: Can you give an example of what that list from the text file is like?

Comment: a list like 5883, 1379, 2764 it just like an id.. anyway thanks... I just found the solution which have to convert it to vector..